# How can I target an element's 'parent'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some `<TD>s` without unique names. Inside them there are spans with unique classnames so I have no problem targetting the spans. How can I target the parent `<td>` so I can change its class?

I want to do something like  `$(".classname").parent("TD").className="newClassclassname"`.

Comment: You can use `.find('.newClass');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close:

```
 $('.classname').parent('td').addClass('newClassName');
```

Though typically it's safer to go with:

```
 $('.classname').closest('td').addClass('newClassName');
```

... which doesn't assume the `<td>` is the *immediate* parent.

---

The reason `.className` doesn't work is because jQuery returns elements wrapped in the jQuery object. If you want to access the original (DOM) object you need to select the first item in the jQuery collection with `[0]`:

```
 $('.classname').parent('td')[0].className = 'newClassName';
```

But I recommend using the jQuery function `addClass()` anyway since it won't interfere with existing classes.

Comment: Actually, `.parents()` would be more appropriate than `.closest()` - `elem.closest('some-selector') === elem` is possible for example

Comment: @ThiefMaster - true, but I'd expect that case to be less severe than selecting multiple `<td>`s in the case of nested tables? Of course you could do `.parents('td:first')`, but it's a bit verbose.

Comment: Ah.. thought it'd stop with the first match.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$("span.classname").closest("td").addClass("newClassclassname");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, do you mean following code:

$(".classname").parent("TD").addClass("newClassName");

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".classname").parent("TD")[0].className="newClassname";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".classname").parent().addClass("newClassclassname");
```